# Disappearing HTML - Function

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator

I am trying to make a small calculator-thingy for my website. I want to be able to write a number in a text-input, then get the double of that number back. I tried this way at first:

```
<form name="form">
<input type="text"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc() {
    var x = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    document.write(x*2);
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onClick="calc()" value="Calculate here"/>
```

This is working fine, but when calling the function ( calc() ) with the button, all HTML is removed. The only thing appearing is the double of the number (variable x) you wrote. I have read that the "function" make all other HTML disappear.

Is it possible to make the page stay the same, but at the same time showing the calculated number (x*2)? Can I reach the variable x without using a function? 
Is it possible to "control" where and how the calculated number (x*2) is going to appear, within the JavaScript or within the HTML?

I am new to this coding art, was hoping to find a relatively easy way to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is probably to add a div outside the form which is intended to reflect the calculated value. Then you can update `calc` to find this div and replace its contents with the calculated value.

```
<script>
    function calc() {
    var x = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    var result = x * 2;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

<form name="form">
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate here"/>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Hope you enjoy programming as much as I do :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your original code and the accepted answer.

Make sure that the value you retrieve is an integer(or a float).This way you will prevent the user from getting weird results.
You can do it like this:

```
<script>
    function calc() {
    var x = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements[0].value);// or parseInt(document.forms[0].elements[0].value)
    var result = x * 2;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

<form name="form">
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate here"/>

<div id="result"></div>
```